# Linux tools for perf (install linux-tools-3.15.0)

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

I use Linaro version of Linux (Linaro 12.11) on my embedded target with ARM9 Core. For a certain profiling, I need to use the **perf** tool. perf require linux-tools-3.15.0 to be installed on my device. But all attempts to do this is going in-vain. Lastly I tried

```
sudo wget --no-check-certificate "https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ppa/+build/5980376/+files/linux-tools-3.15.0-0-generic_3.15.0-0.1_armhf.deb"
```

But it gave the result

```
--1970-01-12 04:57:03--  https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ppa/+build/5980376/+files/linux-tools-3.15.0-0-generic_3.15.0-0.1_armhf.deb
Resolving launchpad.net (launchpad.net)... 91.189.89.222, 91.189.89.223
Connecting to launchpad.net (launchpad.net)|91.189.89.222|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify launchpad.net's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA':
Issued certificate not yet valid.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/5980376/+files/linux-tools-3.15.0-0-generic_3.15.0-0.1_armhf.deb [following]
--1970-01-12 04:57:05--  https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/5980376/+files/linux-tools-3.15.0-0-generic_3.15.0-0.1_armhf.deb
Reusing existing connection to launchpad.net:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
1970-01-12 04:57:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the file does not exists. The `perf` is part of `linux-tools` package as far as I know.

You should be able to install it by traditional way `apt-get install linux-tools` from standard sources. If not, post what happened when you tried and what kernel version are you using.